# GIMP Add touch-up layer after adding curves layer (and other layers)

Tags: gimp, layers, photo-editing

Suppose I add several layers in GIMP to make various adjustments such as color corrections and burning/dodging.  Once the image generally looks good, I then wish to non-destructively (i.e., without flattening the image) make cloning/healing touch ups to remove blemishes.  How can I do this?

More specifically, what kind of layer could I add that would allow me to touch up the subject's skin without losing all the other adjustments?

Comment: Have you tried to [group](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-groups.html) the layers? It could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do that by making a copy the subject layer  itself, and use this copy in "normal mode". Depending on the retouch, I add a layer mask on this copied  layer so that only the touched parts are used. Any errors on this copy can be promptly made transparent or copy-pasted over from the original.